# How can one define a keyboard shortcut for autotyping some text in GNOME 3 on Wayland?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, wayland

In X11 I have many keyboard shortcuts that result in various pieces of text being typed into whatever application I'm using. A representative example is typing a timestamp when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. This is done by setting the following command as a keyboard shortcut:

```
bash -c "sleep 0.1; xvkbd -text $(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ" --utc) 2>/dev/null"
```

These shortcuts are essential to me and I use them perhaps once every minute. How can the same functionality be achieved in Wayland?

Comment: Highly relevant question also for me. I extensively use autotext and macro's that rely on command line clipboard tools and xdotool. All of this does not work in Wayland, so for me Wayland currently is not an option.